# Patch Axios issue

Tags: ruby, rest, vue.js, axios, sinatra

I am building a client in Vue.js and  have a problem while running the patch method in axios, this is my code the URL is just hardcoded for now cause I was just trying it out

```
  axios.patch('http://localhost:9292/companies/1',{
      data:this.company_data
    })
      .then(response => {
        // handle success
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error =>  {
        console.log(error.response)
      });
    }
```

My server is built in Ruby with Sinatra:

```
patch '/companies/:id'do
  content_type :json
  company = Company.get params[:id]
  if company.update params[:company]
    status 200
    json 'Company was updated'
  else
    status 500
    json company.errors.full_messages
  end
end
```

And when I try to run the patch from axios I get this error:

```
 - NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass:
        C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:332:in `attributes='
        C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:385:in `update'
        C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/dm-validations-1.2.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:46:in `block in update'
        C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/dm-validations-1.2.0/lib/dm-validations/context.rb:16:in `in_context'
        C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/dm-validations-1.2.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:46:in `update'
        E:/assignment_company2(server)/server.rb:127:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

But when I do it with curl it works.

```
curl -X PATCH -d "company[name]=andrs" http://localhost:9292/companies/1
"Company was updated"
```

Comment: what's `company_data` look like?

Comment: HTTP 500 is for an internal server error. Thats not the response you should be giving unless you're rescuing from some unrecoverable error.

Comment: @JoshBrody company_data look like this `company_data:{
        name:'',
        adress:'',
        country:'',
        city:'',
        email:'',
        phoneNumber:'',
      },`